# Why is django.test.client.Client not keeping me logged in

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I'm using django.test.client.Client to test whether some text shows up when a user is logged in. However, I the Client object doesn't seem to be keeping me logged in.

This test passes if done manually with Firefox but not when done with the Client object.

```
class Test(TestCase):
    def test_view(self):
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        client = self.client
        # I thought a more manual way would work, but no luck
        # client.post('/login', {'username':user.username, 'password':password})
        login_successful = client.login(username=user.username, password=password)
        # this assert passes  
        self.assertTrue(login_successful)

        response = client.get("/path", follow=True)
        #whether follow=True or not doesn't seem to work

        self.assertContains(response, "needle" )
```

When I print response it returns the login form that is hidden by:

```
{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
    ... form ...
{% endif %}
```

This is confirmed when I run `ipython manage.py shell`.

The problem seems to be that the Client object is not keeping the session authenticated.

Comment: Looking at this I am not sure where the problem is. Can you show definitively that the client is getting logged out? If client is logged in then `client.session != {}` You can use this to show where or if the client is getting logged out.

Comment: That's surely not helping you, sorry, but I have the same problem since today. I don't know what changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, an update to Django 1.2 (I was running 1.1.1 before) fixed it. I have no idea what was broken there, considering when I last ran that test suite about 2 weeks ago, it worked great.

Comment: So you encountered the same problem?

Comment: I also upgraded to Django 1.2 and the problem went away. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just happened to me when retesting an app that has been working and forgotten for some months.

The solution (apart from updating to Django 1.2) is [Patch #11821](http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/11821).  In short, Python 2.6.5 has some bugfix in the Cookie module, triggering an edge case bug in the test client.

Comment: Nice find! This was exactly my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use `RequestContext` to get the logged in user into the template context.

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.template import RequestContext

@login_required
def index(request):
   return render_to_response('page.html',
                             {},
                             context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and in the template

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %} ... {{ user.username }} .. {% endif %}
```

This works as expected (I don't get to this page without logging in, and when I get there, the username is present in `response.content`) when driven through the test client.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. If I weren't importing the context correctly then it wouldn't work in Firefox as well as with Client. The problem is that it does work in Firefox but not with client so I can't test the functionality.

Comment: Your use of request.user.is_authenticated (rather than user.is_authenticated) suggests that you're not using the context. If it didn't work for you via a browser, I'd suspect that you're not passing `{'request': request}` to your template.